# Where did all my files go after git filter-repo

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I fear I am in a load of trouble! I was trying to remove a folder called `notebooks` from my repo's history.

I used `git filter-repo --path notebooks --force`.

This seems to have deleted all of the files that had been in the index in my repo, not just from `notebooks` path; what happened? For the majority of these files, I can just restore from the remote, but the problem is my local branch had not push some important files to the remote before I did this.

Is there a way to recover the files that got deleted??

Comment: What is `filter-repo` ? There is `filter-branch` which is more or less dangerous and deprecated, but at least, it create a backup ref. You should see it using `gitk --all &`: from here, you ought to create a branch, or reset --hardy your (broken) branch from the backup

Comment: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo
The repo says it's very similar to filter-branch. Sorry how can I use gitk to restore the deleted files?

Comment: This definitely does not solve the problem, but for anyone who might have been using a similar set up to me - I found almost all of the files I needed in __pycache__, and decompiled them using uncompyle6

Comment: You missed the `--invert-paths` option so instead of keeping everything but the `notebook` directory you kept only the `notebook` directory.

Comment: That is not a mistake I will make again... Thanks I missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used the `--force` option there is no way to recover your files from this repository (see [documentation of filter-repo `--force`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#FRESHCLONE)):

> Since filter-repo does irreversible rewriting of history, it is important to avoid making changes to a repo for which the user doesn’t have a good backup.

> It is
> an irreversible operation, especially since it by default ends with an immediate pruning of reflogs and old objects

So your only chance is a backup, i.e. you pushed somewhere or someone pulled from you.